# Preventing std::ifstream from creating an empty file

Tags: c++, c++11, file-io, fstream, iostream

The following code will create an empty file if a file with the supplied path is not found:

```
std::ifstream file;
file.open(path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
//file.open(path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary); will set fail() to true

if (!file.is_open())
    throw std::runtime_error("File could not be opened."); //never reached

file.seekg(0, file.end);
size_t size = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, file.beg);

char* buffer = new char[size];
file.read(buffer, size);
file.close();

if (file.fail()) 
    throw std::runtime_error("Error reading file."); //why with only std::ios::in | std::ios::binary?
```

Is there a way to avoid this behavior of `ifstream`? I need to make the operation fail if the file is not found but it always succeeds. Do I have to fall back to `fopen` for this behavior?

Comment: If you open it in read-mode, that should do what you want

Answer (score 4):

[This `std::basic_filebuf::open` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) contains a handy table what happens with the different flags. And as you can see every time `app` is used the behavior is to create a new file if it doesn't exist.

There is a way around this: Open *without* using the `app` flag. This way the open would fail which you can then check for. If it doesn't fail, then you close the file and open again with `app`.

Comment: Thanks! `app` is there because otherwise I get a `fail` state after reading the whole file if I only pass in `in | binary`. Curiously with `in | out | binary` the fail state goes away. Any idea why that happens? I've posted the whole code.

Comment: The out flag makes a non-existing file no longer a problem because it can just create one for you.

Comment: @EnigmaticBacon the fail is with an existing file. If I only set `in` and `binary` flags, the file opens correctly, and the reported size is correct but `fail()` returns `true`. This won't happen either with `app` flag set or `out` flag set. Why?

Comment: @InBetween Well of course you get a "fail" after reading the whole file, when opened in read-only mode. That's kind of the point. :)

Comment: Reading data that isn't there will, naturally, fail. That's a feature. :)

Comment: duh, I', very new to c++. Ok fail is signaling eof, I'm dumb. Thanks!